# Linking errors with qt pcl and vtk

Tags: qt, linker, cmake, vtk, printer-control-language

I am trying to compile the PCL tutorial described [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/qt_visualizer.php) and I am facing these linking errors.

> Linking CXX executable pcl_visualizer usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined
>   reference to `SSL_get_peer_certificate@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0: undefined reference to`
>   TIFFReadDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined
>   reference to `CRYPTO_num_locks@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5:
>   undefined reference to`
>   SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0: undefined reference to
>   `TIFFIsTiled@LIBTIFF_4.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   SSL_use_certificate_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined
>   reference to `ENGINE_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined
>   reference to`OPENSSL_config@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5:
>   undefined reference to `SSL_get_error@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   SSL_use_PrivateKey_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined
>   reference to `X509_STORE_load_locations@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0: undefined reference to`
>   TIFFDefaultStripSize@LIBTIFF_4.0' usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0:
>   undefined reference to `TIFFReadTile@LIBTIFF_4.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5:
>   undefined reference to`SSL_set_ex_data@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0: undefined reference to
>   `TIFFWriteScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0' usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0: undefined
>   reference to`_TIFFfree@LIBTIFF_4.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined
>   reference to `SSL_read@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0:
>   undefined reference to`TIFFGetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
>   usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0: undefined reference to
>   `TIFFScanlineSize@LIBTIFF_4.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined reference
>   to`X509_STORE_set_flags@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined
>   reference to `SSLv23_method@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5:
>   undefined reference to`ENGINE_load_private_key@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `X509_get_subject_name@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined
>   reference to`CRYPTO_set_id_callback@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0: undefined reference to
>   `TIFFClose@LIBTIFF_4.0' usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0: undefined reference
>   to`TIFFClientOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined
>   reference to `SSL_CTX_new@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined
>   reference to`SSL_CTX_get_cert_store@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `SSL_check_private_key@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0:
>   undefined reference to`TIFFGetFieldDefaulted@LIBTIFF_4.0'
>   usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `ENGINE_by_id@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0: undefined
>   reference to`TIFFNumberOfDirectories@LIBTIFF_4.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5:
>   undefined reference to `ERR_get_error@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   CRYPTO_set_locking_callback@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5:
>   undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to`SSL_new@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0:
>   undefined reference to`TIFFOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5:
>   undefined reference to `SSL_write@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5:
>   undefined reference to`X509_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5:
>   undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0: undefined reference to`
>   TIFFReadRGBAImage@LIBTIFF_4.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined
>   reference to `SSL_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined
>   reference to`SSL_ctrl@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0:
>   undefined reference to `TIFFSetField@LIBTIFF_4.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5:
>   undefined reference to`SSL_set_verify@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ENGINE_init@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to`SSL_set_fd@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_connect@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   ERR_reason_error_string@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined
>   reference to `SSL_CTX_ctrl@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5:
>   undefined reference to`SSL_pending@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5:
>   undefined reference to `SSL_use_PrivateKey@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
>   usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0: undefined reference to`
>   TIFFSetWarningHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined
>   reference to `ENGINE_finish@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0:
>   undefined reference to`TIFFSetErrorHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
>   usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0: undefined reference to
>   `_TIFFmalloc@LIBTIFF_4.0' usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to`
>   SSL_library_init@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0: undefined
>   reference to `TIFFSetDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0' usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0:
>   undefined reference to`TIFFReadScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0'
>   usr/lib/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to
>   `SSL_shutdown@OPENSSL_1.0.0' usr/lib/libvtkIO.so.5.8.0: undefined
>   reference to`TIFFNumberOfTiles@LIBTIFF_4.0' collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status make[2]: *** [pcl_visualizer] Error 1 make[1](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/qt_visualizer.php):
>   *** [CMakeFiles/pcl_visualizer.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2

The CmakeList file is define as follow:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

project      (pcl-visualizer)
find_package (Qt4 REQUIRED)
find_package (VTK REQUIRED)
find_package (PCL 1.7.1 REQUIRED)

include_directories (${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories    (${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions     (${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

set  (project_SOURCES main.cpp pclviewer.cpp)
set  (project_HEADERS pclviewer.h)
set  (project_FORMS   pclviewer.ui)
set  (VTK_LIBRARIES   vtkRendering vtkGraphics vtkHybrid QVTK)

QT4_WRAP_CPP (project_HEADERS_MOC   ${project_HEADERS})
QT4_WRAP_UI  (project_FORMS_HEADERS ${project_FORMS})

INCLUDE         (${QT_USE_FILE})
ADD_DEFINITIONS (${QT_DEFINITIONS})

ADD_EXECUTABLE  (pcl_visualizer ${project_SOURCES}
                                ${project_FORMS_HEADERS}
                                ${project_HEADERS_MOC})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (pcl_visualizer ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```

Is there anything missing in the CMakeList file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PostgreSQL library you are linking to is missing openssl, you can check it with

```
ldd /usr/lib/libpq.so.5
```

it should report something like

```
libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
```

The same with vtk, but it doesn't find a valid TIFF library.

First, check that you have both openssl and tiff libraries installed, if linking still fails, check if versions are correct.

Second, if all libraries are installed, check if are from the correct architecture (all 32-bit or all 64-bit).

Third, manually force your project to load libraries flags (both from command line `CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS` / `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` or in the `target_link_libraries` directive).

Comment: When I list the dependencies for libpq.so it rueturn this for libssl `libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f13c113a000)`. I am going to check if there is a version problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The problem was due to Anaconda. That was the first version of Qt which was found, I suspect my install of Anaconda to be 32 bits and the rest to be 64.

Comment: It was my second thought, this could happen when 32 and 64 libraries are mixed.

Comment: Hey I have the same problem: I found out that I have more versions of libssl as well. How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, anaconda is the problem.

Rename your anaconda folder to *anaconda-temp* so that the link in your path variable is incorrect for cmake during its scan. Then install `qt5-default` using `sudo apt-get install qt5-default` as that solved both the errors in my case. Then rerun *cmake* and now it should detect qt5 in the correct location (i.e. not in the anaconda path).

Now run make and then finally you can rename anaconda-temp to anaconda so that it corresponds to your path and the value in bashrc and it's business as usual.

Answer (score 0):

For solving problem with TIFF 4.0 you may try

```
cd $HOME/Downloads
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
sudo ldconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me that you should remove the ananconda3 from your system path. For me, I just remove it from the ~/.bashrc file. And everything works ok.